# Vaio Fan works constantly with little breaks

Tags: fan, sony-vaio

I have a Vaio Z13 and just replaced my fan. The old fan sometimes gave me a high pitch voice, therefore I changed it.

Now I have the problem that the fan works constantly for about a minute and has a break of 3-4 seconds.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Thank you very much

edit: sorry, cannot post images due to reputation restrictions... but I found this in google.
http://www.google.ch/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fi00.i.aliimg.com%2Fphoto%2Fv0%2F601224770%2Ffor_VAIO_VPC_Z1_series_laptop_motherboard.jpg&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fswtcshine.en.alibaba.com%2Fproduct%2F601224770-213910563%2Ffor_VAIO_VPC_Z1_series_laptop_motherboard_MBX_206_100_tested_before_delivery.html&h=331&w=600&tbnid=sMwbuS52229fbM%3A&zoom=1&docid=AUMJE4OuUjHYzM&ei=jN0JVO-MFJPkat-_gIgD&tbm=isch&client=firefox-a&ved=0CFYQMygvMC8&iact=rc&uact=3&dur=1036&page=2&start=27&ndsp=25

I put the thermal paste on the two "cores" but not on the "core" on the right hand side.

Comment: Relaxing the fan is a good idea but you may still have a dust build-up around the fan exhaust/vent or the conductive paste between the CPU and the heatsink may have dried up and isn't conducting the heat away from the CPU efficiently enough. If heat isn't being drawn away from the main processor then it will constantly report it needs cooling - thus turn the fan on :)

Comment: Dear Big Chris, Thank you for your answer. It´s new fan, I cleaned everything before and changed the thermal paste, although I did it little different from the way Sony did. I did put only I thin surface of paste on it and skip the part in "between". Anyway, I have two "heatcores". I saw that for the first time. My notebook is always really cold (well, the fan is working literally working 100% all the time). So you think I should open again and "re-do" the thermal paste?

Comment: Relaxing = replacing, sorry! Two heatcores? Heatsinks? One for main CPU and one for or graphics card? Are they separate or are they on the same pipe to the fan? Ideally you should paste both. A decent amount of paste but never too much that it spills over and not too little.

Comment: I paste all three of them. Two are close together, the other one is extra. But still my fan is doing this disturbing pattern. Could it be the fan itself?

Comment: Doubtful. Are there any settings in BIOS that tell the fan to operate at full rate?

Comment: Unfortunately, BIOS used by common producers like Sony does not provide these configuration possibilities... I wondering if the temperature sensor is defect such that it cannot measure the temperature correctly in order to control the fan.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem (so I give an answer to my question):

between the fan and the gpu was space around 1mm which caused the fan running all the time since there was no cooling for the GPU. As a temporary solution I put a lot thermal paste on it and pressed the fan on it. It run like 2 months and then shutdown all the time, so I also bought some thermal pads 1-1.5mm to exchange them. Since then everything works fine.